# What is the harmonic function of a Eb/F in the Dm tonality?

Tags: harmony

What is the function of the Eb/F chord. How does it relate to the Dm harmonic field?

The question comes from 0:30 time at

Thank you

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It's not clear to me from the video.

Comment: I'd like to know what is the function of the Eb/F chord. That is, how does it relate to the Dm harmonic field? The sheet appears at 0:30 in the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand Eb/F you could start first with Cm/F. This fits well in a bar 5-6 of a Blues in C when you play the head motif just in c-minor instead od transposing it a fourth up: it‘s quite obvious that Cm/F is identical(similar) with F79. So in the Blues F9 is the IV79.

Eb/F (F7911=F11)contains just one 3rd more than F9 and this new note is the 4th. So it could also be written as F9sus4 but Eb/F can be read and deciphered much more quickly.

> What is the harmonic function of a Eb/F in the Dm tonality?

The passage in the video could as well be interpreted in F: vi (V7)/IV

Mind that Dm can be read as substitution of F6. The example  could probably be played as well in F.

**After watching the video I can confirm that we are actually in F. The harmonization will be extended to A7 as secondary dominant of Dm.**

Now you may eventually already have checked that a melody turning to the super dominant can be introduced by secondary dominant7 (V7)/ which I notate in parenthesis and a slash. You can as well consider the whole progression as secondary (IV-V)/Bb or even (iii-IV-V)/IV in F.

**I think the point that the song is in F and the passage in question is a secondary (IV-V) to the subdominant Bb makes it quite easy to understand what’s happening.**

We find quit often a similar progression in minor ii7b5-V/i

or ii7b5-V/vi e.g. in Yesterday (Beatles)

Perhaps you now understand that in these first bars the similar functions are used:

Level 1:

ii-V (Cm-F in bar 2) and Em7b5-A7 in bar 4 (second half)

**Edit**

I'm surprised that this answer ins not clear: 
Dm Eb F is a secondary progression (iii-IV-V) to Bb like Em A7 is a secondary progression (ii-V7) of Dm. I have nothing to add or delete to this answer except that actually I was expecting that someone will tell me that the passing chord (ii-V7) in Yesterday is not quite correct! It is (IIm-V) of VI but follow by a vi. (i.e. Bm7-E7 -> Am)

The example of the Blues I could have deleted as  there is no context with the progression above, but it makes clear how Cm and F9 are related.

Comment: this is the most confusing and wrong answer I have ever seen, so I'm voting down, I can't believe you suggest the tonality changes to F, while it's clear the progression is still inside Dm and doesn't modulate at any point. Are you sure you have watched the correct video in the question above, pointing to time 0:30?

Comment: I agree that it can be confusing as I started explaining the relation of Cm7 and F79 with the Blues example. But it was exactly the way I was approaching to your question without seeing the chord progression. Now why are you so convinced that is Dm? Only because in the first bar it's notated Dm? You say:*I can't believe you suggest the tonality changes to F, while it's clear the progression is still inside Dm and doesn't modulate at any point.* That's accurate what it does: from second bar we are in F with a short extension to the subdominant. IV-V/IV (bar 2-3)and the ii-V/vi (bar 4-1).

Comment: You surely know that Dm is the relative chord of F and Dm7 is identical with F6. It is quite usual that a song begins with vi ii V7 I (and it's a kind of nitpicking when we discuss whether this is not i iv bVII III in minor: Listen to the Concerti Grossi by Handel) To demonstrate that my answer is not wrong I beg you to watch the video 2:12... You wouldn't say we are now in Gm? - and look how t the melody is underlined in bar 3: Bb Gm C7 -> Fmaj7. here we have exactly what I am hearing without looking at the chords: ii V7 -> F. and then the ii-V7 of the vi. My problem was rather the next Gm!

Comment: The reason I'm convinced it's Dm is quite obvious. You probably are not familiar with simple progressions. I will have to go back to the video to write the progression again...

Comment: So here is what we have in the video:
| Dm | Eb/F (wrong notation - should be just F) F | Bb | C | 
analyses:
|| I | V/VI | VI | VII ||

The last chord is a VII, in this symmetry it implies that it's still in Dm and that it's going back to the tonality, since the FUNCTION of the VII chord in Minor Key is of a dominant. Is that clear?

Comment: If we had the original song as an example and in the next bar we had F, then it would make sense to point to the major relative.

Comment: yes! or: Bb = IV and C =V the dominant of F (just play F6 in the 3rd inversion in the next chord. ;) if I listen at the tune I hear it rather in F than Dm minor. What is the title of the song?

Comment: Albrecht, how is Cm/F the same as an F9?  There is no 3 (A) for the F chord.  Within the context of a blues progression, I could understand how it's implied but without that context, we have no reason to think the the chord would have a dominant sound or function.  Eb/F would be a sus chord but without the 4 (Bb), you don't exactly get what you're describing.

Comment: @Bt: In classical music theory you can always let drop in a 4 voices setting of any X9 or X79 chord the 5th or the 3rd, I don't think it is different in Jazz. But as I said, I'm just trying to explain the relation of the function (IV-V) of Bb which is Eb-F and when Eb is above the root note F it is no difference to me whether you say it is  a sus or it is ii-V or IV-V of -> anything. Both progressions are cadencing to the following chord of which the previous is the dominant. I would never brought this argumentation if not after Eb/F there would be following F and Bb.  Only in this context!

Answer (score 2):

They are passing notes, so it's all an F7 chord, V/VI, dominant of Bb. It's not standard notation as the bass should not be on the 9th (Eb/F?). There are only 3 inversions for analysis to make sense: 1st (3rd on the bass), 2nd (5th on the bass), 3rd (7th of the bass).

In other words, it's badly notated. It's only an F7 employed as a secondary dominant.

Comment: I think you could say generally without looking at the video (I didn't watch it) that Eb/F in F is an F7, dominant for Bb. Kids these days look at Youtube too much and play songs too little. ;) +1 for your answer by the way

Comment: @Lyra, don’t you mean V/IV? Btw. I don’t think its bad notated, it’s just an alternative notation which I use too in my head as a shortcut, as it’s easier to understand the progression. I have to admit I have some problems first when starting thinking in Dm.

Comment: @piperi: it is a secondary iv-v/IV like we also often find a secondary (ii-V) Of course we could also consider the noues of Eb as passing tones but it makes sense to interprete them as (IV-V) of Bb,  above F, where F would be a pedal point. Actually this is a similar  discussion as: is C/G the second inversion of the tonic (I46) or a dominant chord with suspended 4th and 6th (V46).

Comment: @Lyra:  my question *you mean V/IV* implies we were in F. So  I'm trying to understand what you're explaining. I know the triads and the functions (R.N) of a D-minor scale. . Eb->F7 is IV->V of Bb = IV in F. **Now in Dm this would  Eb/F (IV) and F (V) of B,  and Bb is VI of Dm**. I've got it! ;) (But in F you can better understand what (Eb-F)/ Bb could be. So I've understood your answer now). But I still don't understand your comment:* (C7 is the **dominant**of G*?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli, good to know things make more sense now! C7 is not in the question, I was just trying to show that your suggestion of V/IV wasn't right, but actually V/IV would be D7 not C7. Sorry about the comment mistake. I wrote above C7 is the dominant of G, which is wrong. C7 is the dominant of F. I meant to say D7 (V/IV).

Comment: yes it, is! Bb is IV in F (I still pretend we can consider this song stands in F ;) and Eb-F is IV-V of Bb.

Comment: It should not be interpreted in F! It's not in the relative key and it doesn't make sense because of the functions in the progression. It starts in Dm and is moving back towards Dm.

Comment: Eb/F is a sus chord and that is a very common/standard notation in the Jazz world.  In no way could you say that this is "badly notated".  This is not an inversion, this is a slash chord and there are many more, for example, Em/F would be a substitute for an Fmaj7 chord.  Your answer is giving very incorrect information in an authoritative voice and could lead someone down the wrong path.

Comment: @Bassticker: Em/F is a good example. You say *Em/F would be a substitute for an Fmaj7 chord*. That's exactly what I mean. I think your last comment was addressed to Lyra - not to me? ;) I agree I don't either like the tone but I will stop now the discussion it will lead to nothing. I can live very good with the thought that the song is in Dm  -  I'd play it in F anyway. I also wouldn't pretend that I HEARD THE VOICE OF JESUS SAY is not in minor only because it turns to the relative major key later. I only used the F major key to explain the passage in question. And if sus or not - so what?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli - Yes, I was addressing Lyra's answer, not your comments.  I may have addressed your comments in another thread, I don't recall.

Comment: @Basstickler and AlbrechtHügli, apologies if my comments sounded a bit 'authoritative' and I agree with other possible interpretations of this analysis (Dm or F, that's fine I agree). For the slash chord, I've seen the 9th on the bass plenty of times, especially in jazz, but from my view, this is commonly used to facilitate the reading (for guitar for instance). In terms of analysing a musical piece, traditionally there are only 3 inversions, and these rules help to define chord's functions and progressions. It's not badly notated for performance, but for an instructional video, I think so.

Comment: @Lyra it’s not an inversion. That’s the difference. F is the root of the chord and it’s a sus chord.

Comment: I completely agree it's not an inversion and it's a sus chord. That's why the notation is wrong, that's not how a sus chord is notated. It could be Fsus for example. But not a slash chord, which indicates an inversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eb/F like you would use F7: for moving to a Bb based chord. Try it: whenever there's an F7 chord in any song, replace it with Eb/F. Do you like how it sounds? There are many other substitutions for F7, for example Cm and B9.

The most important note here, when using it as harmonic leverage to move towards a Bb chord is Eb. The other notes of Eb major chord, G and Bb, are not as important. **Not all notes in a chord are equally important.** We're using these macro building blocks that have at least three notes and we call them "chords", but it doesn't mean that you need a whole chord to affect the "harmonic field" like you say. You don't, you can move the harmony around even with single individual notes. Chords are just more powerful weapons, like "harmonic explosives". The more notes there are, the greater the destructive potential. But with careful placing of even small devices, individual notes, a skillful player can do big things. Listen to, for example, jazz sax soloists who play with only drums as the accompaniment. It's not a polyphonic instrument but the players can still manipulate harmony.

Comment: OK, but what is the theoretical justification? I can see that Eb/F and F7 only share one note (F). To move to a Bb I would use a B7, which shares the tritone with F7

Comment: Really, try it in practice first. Did you already try all the substitutions I listed here? Can you identify any common pattern between Eb/F, F7 and Cm? Why does Cm work as an F7? Even Eb without the F can work as F7. Did you already try it? Hint: quite often the _only_ note you need to do "F7" is Eb. If you're in F major or D minor tonality, just a single Eb note may do the job.

Comment: I see now that Eb is the sub-dominant of Bb. In the video, Eb-F-Bb is a classic IV-V-I progression. Cm also acomplishes sub-dominant function since it is the II degree. I think I get it now

Comment: Not all notes in a chord are equal. For some reason we're using triads a lot and calling three-note combinations "chords", but it doesn't mean that you need "chords" to affect the "harmonic field" like you say. Good term by the way, did you invent it?

Comment: I translated from spanish "campo armónico" since I am not a native english speaker

Comment: @JuanTopo - Eb/F and F7 share F and Eb., not only F. Eb/F is sometimes called F11.

Comment: @Tim the F note in Eb/F isn't very important as a harmony influencer, it's more like a rather colorless, odorless non-operation, compared to the Eb. The F just adds a bit of extra flavor to the Eb note, IMO. It just occurred to me that it might be better in general to emphasize the importance of understanding the role of each individual note separately. Many students (?) seem to think of chords too much as stand-alone musical entities, almost like physical objects and laws of nature, instead of cultural and practical conventions.

Comment: @piiperi - that F note for me is the base/bass of the chord (it would be, being a slash note!) but what I mean is that for me it's far more like a derivative of an F chord, with root in the bass. It  usually leads to a chord 4 above - here Bb. So F11 seems like a better name.

Comment: I’d say: the most logical  interpretation is  IV-V of Bb (IV in F) over F which is  the root from F7 - as secondary dominant of Bb.

Comment: @Tim if you transform the "is" sentence to a "does" sentence ... in the context of first being in F, what the Eb/F chord effectively _does_ to the harmony comes mostly from the Eb note, not from any other note, not even the root . :) Leave out the Eb note and the harmonic impact is reduced, but leave out any of the others, including the root F, and most of the essential thing is still intact. IMO.

Comment: Eb/F is a sus chord and substitutes for F.  If you only have Eb, you're not exactly getting the dominant feel.  Sure, Eb has a certain dissonance that wants to resolve to a chord tone of your Bb, but if you're only playing Eb, it's more like a plagal cadence or strictly outlining the melodic activity.  Historically speaking, F and A would be the only important notes to push back to Bb.  The use of a 7 on your dominant chord is far removed from dominant functionality's inception, so to claim it to be the most important not only defies what I hear but also history.

Comment: @Basstickler You don't get it. You don't only have an Eb. You _play_ an Eb note but that's not the first and the last note ever played, there is a context of things that have sounded before it. You've played stuff in F major, and bringing in an Eb is a change to that picture. Playing an F note would not be a change or disruption in the same sense. Sure, if you wait an hour, go jogging and have dinner, and _then_ play just a single note, it's different and maybe you want to provide more background by using other notes as well.

Comment: @piiperi I'm saying that in a normal context, where we're in Bb (or going there), the Eb note will not in and of itself provide the same sort of dissonance to have a satisfactory resolution to Bb, where F does have this feeling all on its own.  You seem to be suggesting that Eb has more of a dominant function than F and I am just suggesting that the Eb on its own does not have that function, even within the context of the key.  The only diatonic rival to F for a dominant feel would be the A.

Answer (score 1):

Eb/F with respect to Dm?  Key, Tension, & Tonality is important.

Albeit missing harmonic opportunities, simple options include seeing Eb/F in Eb Lydian (as SubDom, adding b9 & #5 further asserts this, as does adding b7 & #5 for a Blue [I has either 3/b3] Tonality) or Eb Ionian (as Tonic, adding b9 & #11 further asserts this, as does adding b9 & b3 for a Blue [I has either 3/b3] Tonality), given the suspended (avoiding I's 3rd, ∆7, and especially #5) nature of the 7sus chord built.

If D Minor is meant as iim to C Major (typically relative minor to F as IV chord, extendable with 6 & 9, typically SubDom, 'building tension'), as is implied by it being Dm/C as Dm7 being followed by G7 as C's V7, which supports a SubDom to Dom movement of Tension in Major Tonality in Key of C (homed to D) ...

... Eb/F cannot (with its Eb/b3 and Bb/b7) be in C Major (D Dorian Minor), but rather, especially as a 2nd bar after a SubDom chord in C Major, like Dm or F variants, lifts the harmony into Eb Lydian, most effectively as Tonic as a temporary tensionless moment, albeit in another key, as Eb Lydian Tonic in a Blues Tonality, that is, with a b9 & b7 on Eb Lydian for Eb Lydian TONIC BLUE as {Eb,E,F,G,A,Bb,C,Db,D} or Bb Ionian TONIC BLUE {Bb,C,Db,D,Eb,E,F,G,A}.

If D Minor is meant as VIm in F Major (typically relative minor to F Major, implying that D has a b6, Bb, rather than a 6, the B it'd be for a ii in C Major), and often in a Tonic ('[temporarily] released tension') Tension for F Major (homed to D) ...

... Eb/F cannot (with its Eb/b3) be in F Major (D Aoelian Minor), but rather, can (also) be seen as lifting the harmony into another Key/Tonality/Tension, with among choices, Eb∆7(#11)/F {F,eb,a,bb,d} making Eb Lydian TONIC BLUE as {Eb,E,F,G,A,Bb,C,Db,D} on F, or Eb∆7b6/F {F,eb,bb,b,d} making Ab Lydian SUBDOM MINOR as {Ab,Bb,Cb,Db,D,Eb,E,F,G} on F, noting how D & E tonicize Eb as the SubDom key centre atop F.

If D Minor is meant as Im Tonic in what truly is D Minor (and not just an Aeolian/vi or Dorian/ii relative minor of F or C)--D Melodic Minor, which, for it's full 9-note Key/Tonality/Tension, for D/Minor/Tonic can be seen as D Lydian Minor with added 11 & b9 or (as, to me, Minor Harmony arrives by the IV/Lydian's 3rd or I/Ionian's 6th being flattened), less appealingly, D Dorian with added b5 + b9, noting that the b9, the Eb, tonicizes, 'forces as home' the I, the D ...

... Although the Eb can be the tonicizing b9 for D Lydian Minor in a SubDom function, Eb/F, in the context of Dm as Im(∆), perhaps following the Eb/F, but not necessarily, is likely best seen in Eb Lydian SUBDOM MAJOR {Eb,F,F#,G,A,Bb,B,C,D}, with the F# being Ebs #9 and the B being Eb's #5.  Note how Eb/F is effectively expanded by added, first the A {F,A,Bb,Eb,G} and moving it to the B {F,Bb,B,Eb,G} prior to moving to a Dm∆ {D,A,C#,F}.

Happy to discuss a 9-note framework for Key, Tonality (I Major, I/vi Blue, and I Minor), and Tension (SubDom, Dom, Tonic)!

Comment: Blimey!   That's a sledgehammer of an answer!

Comment: Hi Laurence.  On your profile, the "'Notes outside the scale do not necessarily affect the tonality'. Walter Piston, Harmony." is super-cool.  Thx.  Hadn't encountered.  Will seek.  On Gmail, Elliot

Comment: Yes, a chromatic note/chord doesn't HAVE to be analysed as a modulation, a 'borrowing' or a new 'tonal centre'.  Perhaps it's just chromatic!